# Statistical order of the eigenvector for a positive semi-definite matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-semidefinite

I have a $N\times N$ sample covariance matrix of the form $S_{xx},$ which of
rank $k$ such that $k\ll N.$ You can think about that $k=5$ but $N=1000$.
Since $S_{xx}$ is a positive semidefinite matrix with at most $k$ nonzero
eigenvalues, from the construction of $S_{xx},$ I know that the summation
of of all eigenvalues of $S_{xx}$ is of order $O\left( N\right) ,$ i.e.,
proportional to $N.$ Now I establish that there exists a $N\times 1$ vector $%
\mathbf{a}$ such that $\mathbf{a}^{\prime }S_{xx}\mathbf{a}\rightarrow 0$,
as $N\rightarrow \infty,$ where $\mathbf{a}^{\prime }\mathbf{a} \neq 1$. Is there any rigorous way to find the order of $%
\mathbf{a,}$ i.e., $\mathbf{a}=O\left( N^{-1}\right) $ or $\mathbf{a}%
=O\left(N^{-(1+\epsilon )}\right) $ for some $\epsilon >0?$.

For simplicity, I can assume $\mathbf{a}=c \mathbf{1}_N$, where $\mathbf{1}_N$ is a $N \times 1$ vector of ones, I want to find the order of $c$ such that $ c^2\mathbf{1}_N^{\prime }S_{xx}\mathbf{1}_N\rightarrow 0$, for instance, $c$ could be proportional to $N^{-1}$. Many thanks!

Comment: do you also want to assume that a is a unit vector? otherwise a could just be 0. on the other hand, if you assume that a is a unit vector, then you obtain the uninteresting answer a=O(1). am i missing something?

Comment: Hi Mark, I have updated my question to be clearer. In my work, I can't assume $a$ is a unit vector. Thanks

Comment: even with the edits, it seems that you could still just let a=0

Comment: Yes, $a=0$ will of course satisfy the condition, but it is pretty much useless for the work I am on it. I am looking for a particular order such as $c=N^{-1}$, something like that. Thanks again!

Comment: then please edit the question to include exactly what restrictions you want to place on a

Comment: I mentioned in the end of the first paragraph that I want to rigorously show something like  $a=O(N^{-1})$.

Comment: well if a=0 then $a\leq 1/N$ so you have a=O(1/N) and you done

Comment: $a \neq 0$, nor I mentioned that $a$ is zero, since the $limit$ of $a^{\prime}S_{xx}a \to 0$, as $N \to $ $ \infinity$. So the limit of the quadratic form is zero, which is not exactly 0. Otherwise it is a trivial case.